# What is wrong with this linq query?

Tags: vb.net, linq

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ds As DataSet
    ds = getData()
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim gridViewData = From r As DataRow In dt.Rows Select r.Item("foo"), r.Item("bar")
    GridView1.DataSource = gridViewData
    GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

I just wrote the preceeding code and I get the following compile-time error: "Range variable name can be inferred only from a simple or qualified name with no arguments".  Why do I get this error?  How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, I understand the problem now. It's in the projection. Try this:

```
Dim gridViewData = From r As DataRow In dt.Rows _
                   Select Foo = r.Item("foo"), Bar = r.Item("bar")
```

Basically it didn't know what to call the properties in the projection.

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies: I've updated my answer, now I think I understand it.

Comment: @Jon It seems VB.NET requires you to explicity express the property names.  I'm curious, would C# infer the property names from the column names so that you didn't have to define them in the projection?

Comment: @Ben: VB will infer property names if you're using a simple property, I believe... but in this case we're calling an indexer, effectively. C# wouldn't guess it from the arguments either - you'd need something similar. (See James's answer.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I don't know the VB syntax for this, so I'll just have to show the C# and hope you can work it out:

```
from DataRow r in dt.Rows
select new 
{
     r.Item("Foo"),
     r.Item("bar")
}
```

This is saying "Create a new class with two properties", but it has no idea what you want those properties named.  If you had done something like this:

```
from DataRow r in dt.Rows
select new 
{
     r.Count,
     r.NumRows
}
```

Then it would assume that you wanted the properties called `Count` and `NumRows`,  but with yours, all it has to go on is `Item`, which is used by both.

It fix this, you must specify names, explicitly:

```
from DataRow r in dt.Rows
select new 
{
     Foo = r.Item("Foo"),
     Bar = r.Item("bar")
}
```